# looping difficulty with data

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop, apply

i can covert one column into  climdexInput object format using the following code :

```
tmax.dates <- as.PCICt(do.call(paste, t[,c("year",
                                           "days")]), format="%Y %j", cal="gregorian")
tmin.dates <- as.PCICt(do.call(paste, t[,c("year",
                                             "days")]), format="%Y %j", cal="gregorian")
prec.dates <- as.PCICt(do.call(paste, t[,c("year",
                                           "days")]), format="%Y %j", cal="gregorian")
## Load the data in.
ci <- climdexInput.raw(tmax=ntuobs[,1],
                       tmin=ntuobs[,1],
                       prec=ntuobs[,1],tmax.dates, tmin.dates, prec.dates, base.range=c(2000, 2010))
## Create a timeseries of monthly maximum 5-day consecutive
```

however, ntuobs[] has 100 columns and i want apply the function on all 100 columns and then store it into 100 ci[,] columns .

"i tried applying for loop

```
for (i in 1:100){
ci[,i] <- climdexInput.raw(tmax=ntuobs[,i],
                       tmin=ntuobs[,i],
                       prec=ntuobs[,i],tmax.dates, tmin.dates, prec.dates, base.range=c(2000, 2010))
} "
```

but this gives an error

```
"Error in ci[, i] <- climdexInput.raw(tmax = changi[, i], tmin = ntuobs[,  : 
  object of type 'S4' is not subsettable"
```

kindly suggest me ways to tackle this problem. Any loop methods using APPLY function is welcomed.
Thanks

**example dataset**

```
library(PCICt)
## Create a climdexInput object from some data already loaded in and
## ready to go.
## Parse the dates into PCICt.
tmax.dates <- as.PCICt(do.call(paste, ec.1018935.tmax[,c("year",
"jday")]), format="%Y %j", cal="gregorian")
tmin.dates <- as.PCICt(do.call(paste, ec.1018935.tmin[,c("year",
"jday")]), format="%Y %j", cal="gregorian")
prec.dates <- as.PCICt(do.call(paste, ec.1018935.prec[,c("year",
"jday")]), format="%Y %j", cal="gregorian")
## Load the data in.
ci <- climdexInput.raw(ec.1018935.tmax$MAX_TEMP,
ec.1018935.tmin$MIN_TEMP, ec.1018935.prec$ONE_DAY_PRECIPITATION,
tmax.dates, tmin.dates, prec.dates, base.range=c(1971, 2000))
## Create a timeseries of annual SDII values.
sdii <- climdex.sdii(ci)
```

***but this is  for a single column but mine data is 100 column(ensemble).***

Comment: Please show some example dataset and the names of package that has the functions `as.PCICt`

Comment: @akrun please find the sample data in the edited code (bottom) the package name is climdex.pcic .thanks

Comment: I will check it.  But, where is `ec.1018935.tmax`.  Are these datasets in the same package

Comment: yep in the same package .

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the data in the package.  Please paste the output of `dput(yourdata[1:10,1:4])`

Comment: The package has been on CRAN for about a year. As far as I can tell there is no associated dataset named `ec.1018935.tmax`.

Comment: It's possible to construct a value for `ec.1018935.tmax` using the first example in the help page for `climdex.pcic::climdexInput.raw` , but then the problem becomes apparent when running your code. The `ci` object is a complicated S4 list for which there is no way to use the construction `ci[ , i] <- ...`. You need to understand the data structures in your chosen packages. They are not just vectors or even dataframes. Voting to close as not a constructive question.